# Autoloader.php error

Tags: php, symfony, autoloader

I'm getting a weird error on a project in prod environment

> The autoloader expected class "Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Configurator\Configurator" to be defined in file "/var/www/clients/client1/web18/web/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Configurator/Configurator.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Everything works fine in localhost, I tried to update everything using composer, still getting the same error.

Comment: When strange things happen and I cannot find why, I often remove vendors folder and clean composer.lock file then run composer install. Only when I'm sure what I'm doing wouldn't cause problem to any other developers in my team so on. It's up to you to have a go, or maybe not.

Comment: Indeed, came from the vendor ! Thank you

Comment: Have you sorted it out?